# Why does cargo run rebuilds the binary everytime I run it?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

`cargo run` seems to build my app every time I run it. When there are no code changes it still tried to build it which takes 5 or 8 seconds. This says "building..." and lists all warnings.

Is there a way to simply run my binary with cargo run that will not try to build it?

I'd like it for be built only when something changed.

Comment: To just run your binary you simply run the executable; skipping cargo entirely. That said, cargo should not rebuild anything if you haven't done any changes to your code. It seems like you need to provide more information as this is not common behavior.

Comment: On my machine, when there are really no changes, `cargo run` is instantaneous.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including the `Cargo.toml` and `build.rs` if you have one.

Comment: What version of rustc?  Incremental compilation has been disabled by default [since rust 1.52.1](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/10/Rust-1.52.1.html).

Comment: @eggyal `rustc 1.52.1 (9bc8c42bb 2021-05-09)`

Comment: Well then, that’s probably your answer.  You can override by setting the `RUSTC_FORCE_INCREMENTAL` envvar, but could end up hitting fingerprint failures if the cache is corrupted.  If you do force incremental, then the first time will still be a full build (to construct the cache) but subsequent occasions should then avoid it.

Comment: @eggyal note that the OP is not talking about incremental compilation since he said: "_When there are no code changes_ it still tried to build." When there are no code changes it shouldn't rebuild anything.

Comment: @Jmb: as far as I’m aware, rustc only determines that there are no code changes via incremental compilation?

Comment: @eggyal `cargo run` avoided rebuilding in the absence of code changes long before `rustc` was able to do incremental compilation.